# List of Selenium RC browser launchers

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am trying to find a full list of Selenium RC browser launchers. So far I've not been able to  find any documentation that lists them all. I've gathered the following ones from various sources.

- *iexplore - Launches IE
- *firefox - Launches Firefox
- *safari - Launches Safari
- *opera - Launches Opera
- *googlechrome - Launches Google Chrome
- *chrome - Launches special Firefox profile with elevated security privileges, to bypass Javascript security errors
- *iehta - Launches IE with elevated security privileges
- *piiexplore - Launches IE in proxy injection mode
- *pifirefox - Launches Firefox in proxy injection mode
- *custom - Launches your own custom browser executable

Are there any others lurking out there? Is there any source of documentation on how each one is used?

Comment: Interesting, I did a google search for this list and this question came up before the SeleniumHQ website

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you try and start a selenium session with the wrong browser id

e.g.

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", server.getPort(),
                "*gf", "http://www.eviltester.com");
```

Then selenium 1.0.3 will report the following list:

Supported browsers include:

- firefox
- mock
- firefoxproxy
- pifirefox
- chrome
- iexploreproxy
- iexplore
- firefox3
- safariproxy
- googlechrome
- konqueror
- firefox2
- safari
- piiexplore
- firefoxchrome
- opera
- iehta
- custom

This lists a few more than you have.

Comment: That's awesome. I'd also love to know if there is any documentation on their uses anywhere... seems odd that it wouldn't be in the manual! Getting the full list of supported launchers is a great place to start though.

Comment: Just a note for anyone wanting to do this from the command line. Start Selenium RC with `java -jar selenium-server.jar -interactive` and then enter `cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=*asdf&2=http://www.google.com`