# How to run a Selenium IDE test using Selenium Server

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I have a couple selenium ide saved files for running tests. To be able to run these tests through IE, I have installed selenium server with iedriverserver.

I have created a session but I can only load webdriverjs script. Is there an easy way to convert the selenium ide scripts into a format that can be run by the selenium server?

Is there another/easier way to run selenium ide tests for the IE? Thanks.

Comment: That depends on your definition of "easy". Selenium IDE has an export feature, under the File menu, that allows you to export the test into a language of your choice, and run them from a framework of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files generated by the IDE can be run with the server.

> java -jar "[path to the Selenium server .jar file]" -htmlSuite "*[browser, see the [list here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2572212/2676531)]" "[URL that the browser will navigate to at startup]" "[path to your HTML test suite file made in the IDE]" "[path to the HTML results file that the server will write]"

[This page talks about this process for further reading](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Running_IDE_scripts_with_Selenium_RC).

Comment: Looks to be correct since it works for firefox but for IE I am getting errors. I cannot change my IE settings since it is enforced as a group policy, I am marking it as correct.